# Weighted variance of a small sample

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-theory, statistical-inference

I am trying to calculate the variance of a small sample. I have the data:

```
    PSU STRATUM WEIGHTS COUNTS
1   1   1          2    1
2   2   1          1    1
3   3   1          1    1
4   3   1          1    1
5   2   1          1    1
6   2   1          1    1
7   1   1          1    1
8   1   1          1    2
```

I have the variance calculated from R with the output:

```
       variance     SE
COUNTS  0.11287 0.0829
```

The mean that I calculated was $\mu=1.1111$. To compute the variance I used the formula

$$\sigma_{weighted}^2 = \dfrac{\sum_{i=1}^Nw_i(x_i-\mu)^2}{\sum_{i=1}^N w_i} $$
The answer I got from this was 0.09876543.

Any help or comments would be greatly appreciated.

$\bf{UPDATE:}$ I found an article for a weighted variance given by

$$ Var(\bar{x}_w) = \dfrac{\sum_{i=1}^Nw_i^2}{(\sum_{i=1}^Nw_i)^2}\sigma_{weighted}$$

The answer I got with this was 0.1207133 which is still off.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your answer calculated the biased weighted variance, and I think you are probably more interested in the [unbiased weighted variance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weighted_arithmetic_mean#Weighted_sample_variance), which is a bit trickier to calculate. The formula is:
$$
s^2_{\textrm{weighted}} = \frac{\sum_{i=1}^N w_i}{\left(\sum_{i=1}^N w_i\right)^2 - \sum_{i=1}^N w_i^2}\cdot\sum_{i=1}^N w_i \left(x_i - \mu\right)^2
$$
where
$$
\mu = \frac{\sum_{i=1}^N w_i x_i}{\sum_{i=1}^N w_i}
$$

In your example, the result should be:
$$\frac{9}{9^2 - 11}\cdot \frac{8}{9} = \frac{4}{35}\approx 0.114285714285714$$

Comment: Thank you Avraham I tried this formula also so it lets me know there was an error in my calculations. I wasn't sure If I was using a wrong formula or if something was going wrong with my calculations. Thank you!

Comment: Weighted SD is just the square root of weighted variance, so calculate the weighted variance and take its square root with no other manipulations necessary.